# unable to install blueman on ubuntu 20.04 while bluetooth not working

Tags: 20.04, python, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

after installation of ubuntu 20.04 on my old asus (x550vb) laptop my bluetooth is not working. I have dualboot with windows and bluetooth is working fine there. What I found that bluetooth package http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu is not available for ubuntu focal. I tried to switch to apt bionic packages but it doesn't seems to work.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jan 06 15:36:02 guliver-X550VB systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

When I try to restart bluetooth service it shows status OK but not every time. Sometimes this doesn't happen and it remain inactive.

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[   94.282665] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   94.282706] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   94.282711] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   94.282713] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   94.282718] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 1949.711304] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 1949.711310] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 1949.711315] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

It also seems that Bluetooth is not found with command below. I don't understand why.

```
sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I found solutions that include installing blueman but the installation is failing. I also tried to install python3.7 (also python3.6) and change system python priority to older version with command `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` but this didn't help.

```
apt-get install blueman

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 blueman : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What could solve this problem?
Cheers!

#### Upates:

##### bluetooth device vendor (combined wifi/bt chip)

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e074]
    Kernel driver in use: mt76x0e
    Kernel modules: mt76x0e
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e069 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 145f:0263 Trust Trust Wireless Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

##### apt-cache policy blueman python3 bluez bluetooth (BEFORE restoration of the default repositories)

```
blueman:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.5-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     2.0.5-1ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2.0.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
python3:
  Installed: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.7-1~18.04 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.6.5-3 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
bluez:
  Installed: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 5.53-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.48-0ubuntu3.7 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.48-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
bluetooth:
  Installed: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 5.53-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.48-0ubuntu3.7 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
     5.48-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

##### apt-cache policy blueman python3 bluez bluetooth (AFTER restoration of the default repositories)

```
blueman:
  Installed: 2.1.2-1
  Candidate: 2.1.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.2-1 500
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3:
  Installed: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
bluez:
  Installed: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 5.53-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.53-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
bluetooth:
  Installed: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 5.53-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.53-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

I managed to install blueman (thanks for the suggestion). But bluetooth still does not work due to "No adapter found/missing". I tried to enable bluetooth manager but it fails, see logs below. Also bluetooth service daemon is running without any errors.

##### blueman-manager

```
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-manager 12.11.38 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 12.11.38 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

##### sudo bluetoothctl devices

```
No default controller available
```

##### systemctl status bluetooth

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-01-07 12:21:16 CET; 4min 46s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1203 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9331)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1203 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 07 12:21:16 guliver-X550VB systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 07 12:21:16 guliver-X550VB bluetoothd[1203]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Jan 07 12:21:16 guliver-X550VB bluetoothd[1203]: Starting SDP server
Jan 07 12:21:16 guliver-X550VB systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 07 12:21:16 guliver-X550VB bluetoothd[1203]: Bluetooth management interface>
```

##### dmesg | grep -i firmware

Does the Firmware Bug mean I need different firmware in order to make bluetooth work?

```
[    0.161743] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.317209] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.308933] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
[   12.916805] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware Version: 1.0.07
```

Comment: try to keep the focus. First: if you have problems wih bluetooth, why don't check if the drivers for your device are installed? what is the bluetooth device vendor?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy blueman python3 bluez bluetooth` to the question. Why do you think you need a PPA?

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. I updated original question and provided logs and additional info. Managed to install blueman but bluetooth still doesn't function. Sorry for the confusion in the question.

Comment: I marked this question as solved because blueman is now installed but its only partially solved. Bluetooth still does not work.